# Bootstrap 4 repsonsive layout messed up

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

while working on my layout for my website the whole css got messed up to the point where I cant see the forest trough the trees anymore.

On desktop size everything looks ok-ish, except that the text next to the icon (in the fiddle it floats on top of the text for some reason) gets squashed together, I do not get how I can get it to show the whole sentence on one line. Then when you resize the website I lose the whole 3 icon+text parts under the carousel and collapsed menu. Preferably I would like the menu to expand under the 3 icon+text parts.

No idea how I can get it to show up right as soon as it resizes.

https://jsfiddle.net/adyzv8yu/

```css
#mu-carousel .carousel-item {
    max-height: 480px;
    width: 100%;
}

.mu-nav-collapse .navbar-nav{
    float:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.mpush {
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.navbar-nav >li{
    text-align: left;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu
{
    border: none;
    background-color: white;
}

.sticky-top {
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggler {
    background: darkgrey;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mpush {
        margin-top: -28px;
    }
    #mu-carousel {
        margin-top: -28px;
    }
    .mu-nav {
        margin-top: -28px;
        background: white;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float:none;
        margin:0 auto;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar-nav >li {
        background: white;
    }

    .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu
    {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .mu-nav-bg {
        background: white;
    }

    .sticky-top {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1020;
    }
}

#mu-header {
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 135px;
}

.mu-header-logo {
    height: 85px;
    width: auto;
}

.mu-header-area {
    margin-top: 35px;
    height: 85px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 0.1;
}

.mu-header-area i{
    float:left;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.icon-tex-title{
    padding-top: 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.icon-tex-subtitle{
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>


  

<header id="mu-header" style="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                <span class="mu-header-logo">
                    <img src="http://www.cablecorporation.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/dummy-logo.png" alt="">
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 d-flex d-md-none justify-content-end navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right2 mu-nav-collapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="mu-header-area">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
                    <p class="icon-tex-title">1234-123456</p>
                    <p class="icon-tex-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="mu-header-area">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
                    <p class="icon-tex-title">1234-123456</p>
                    <p class="icon-tex-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="mu-header-area t">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
                    <p class="icon-tex-title">1234-123456</p>
                    <p class="icon-tex-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container sticky-top mpush mu-nav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="mu-carousel" class="mpush">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution does NOT require any `float`. On the contrary, a Bootstrap-friendly solution requires *less* custom css, not more.

So, I have commented out many of your custom css rules because they are either unnecessary or contribute to breaking Bootstrap. See my comments in the code snippet below in regards to some of the replacements I made there.

The solution to the main problem was to replace `height: 135px;` with `min-height: 135px;` for the `#mu-header`.

The solution for the icons problem was to move `<i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>` inside the paragraph element.

Now, since I completely removed or replaced some of your custom css classes (I commented them out in the code snippet below), you can also remove those classes from the HTML code.

As a bonus, I have also made the columns more responsive using the `col-8 col-md-3 col-lg-6` classes for the logo and `col-md-3 col-lg-2` classes for the other items.

Here's the working code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<style>
    #mu-carousel .carousel-item {
        max-height: 480px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mu-nav-collapse .navbar-nav{
        float:none;
        margin:0 auto;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .mpush {
        margin-top: -8px;
    }

    .navbar-nav >li{
        text-align: left;
        background: white;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu
    {
        border: none;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .sticky-top {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navbar-toggler {
        background: darkgrey;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .mpush {
            margin-top: -28px;
        }
        #mu-carousel {
            margin-top: -28px;
        }
        .mu-nav {
            margin-top: -28px;
            background: white;
        }
        .navbar-nav {
            float:none;
            margin:0 auto;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .navbar-nav >li {
            background: white;
        }

        .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu
        {
            background-color: white;
        }

        .mu-nav-bg {
            background: white;
        }

        .sticky-top {
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 1020;
        }
    }

    #mu-header {
        background: lightgrey;
/*        height: 135px; replaced with min-height: 135px; */
        min-height: 135px;
    }

/*
    .mu-header-logo {
        height: 85px;
        width: auto;
    }
*/

    .mu-header-area {
/*        margin-top: 35px; replaced with responsive classes: `mt-0 mt-md-4` */
/*        height: 85px;*/
/*        width: auto;*/
/*        line-height: 0.1;*/
    }

/*
    .mu-header-area i{
        float:left;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
*/

    .icon-tex-title{
        padding-top: 6px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

/*
    .icon-tex-subtitle{
        font-size: 11px; replaced with the `small` class
    }
*/
</style>

<header id="mu-header" style="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
                <span class="mu-header-logo">
                    <img src="http://www.cablecorporation.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/dummy-logo.png" alt="">
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 d-flex d-md-none justify-content-end navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right2 mu-nav-collapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                        data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mt-0 mt-md-4 pl-md-5 pr-md-0 pl-lg-3">
                <div class="mu-header-area">
                    <p class="icon-tex-title mb-1">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i> 1234-123456</p>
                    <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit sit sit sit sit sit sit sit</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mt-0 mt-md-4 pl-md-5 pr-md-0 pl-lg-3">
                <div class="mu-header-area">
                    <p class="icon-tex-title mb-1">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i> 1234-123456</p>
                    <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 mt-0 mt-md-4 pl-md-5 pr-md-0 pl-lg-3">
                <div class="mu-header-area t">
                    <p class="icon-tex-title mb-1">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i> 1234-123456</p>
                    <p class="small">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container sticky-top mpush mu-nav">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="mu-carousel" class="mpush">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

For the icon columns I used these responsive spacing classes:

`mt-0 mt-md-4 pl-md-5 pr-md-0 pl-lg-3`

More info about the use of spacing classes:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: Thanks, this worked very well! I did not know about the spacing in bootstrap yet, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your menu appear below your icons at a small width, you'll need to `float` your `.container` to the `left` at small widths:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

As for your text squashing together, that doesn't happen in the StackSnippet (though it does in the JSFiddle). I assume this is because it doesn't have enough `width` to display properly. This is because you have used an incorrect number of Bootstrap columns inside of your `<header>`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8 col-md-6"></div>
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap columns must **always** add up to 12, and yours add up to 18. Correcting this to the following structure (totalling 12) should resolve this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#mu-carousel .carousel-item {
  max-height: 480px;
  width: 100%;
}

.mu-nav-collapse .navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.mpush {
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  text-align: left;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.sticky-top {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  background: darkgrey;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mpush {
    margin-top: -28px;
  }
  #mu-carousel {
    margin-top: -28px;
  }
  .mu-nav {
    margin-top: -28px;
    background: white;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    background: white;
  }
  .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .mu-nav-bg {
    background: white;
  }
  .sticky-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
  }
}

#mu-header {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 135px;
}

.mu-header-logo {
  height: 85px;
  width: auto;
}

.mu-header-area {
  margin-top: 35px;
  height: 85px;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 0.1;
}

.mu-header-area i {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.icon-tex-title {
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.icon-tex-subtitle {
  font-size: 11px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<header id="mu-header" style="">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="mu-header-logo">
          <img src="http://www.cablecorporation.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/dummy-logo.png" alt="">
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 d-flex d-md-none justify-content-end navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right2 mu-nav-collapse" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="mu-header-area">
          <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
          <p class="icon-tex-title">1234-123456</p>
          <p class="icon-tex-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="mu-header-area">
          <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
          <p class="icon-tex-title">1234-123456</p>
          <p class="icon-tex-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="mu-header-area t">
          <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
          <p class="icon-tex-title">1234-123456</p>
          <p class="icon-tex-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container sticky-top mpush mu-nav">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown link
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<section id="mu-carousel" class="mpush">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah yes you are totally right about the cols but this still breaks my layout, the carousel controls go out of bounds, the hamburger is only half clickable if you size down the screen.